# How to pass a control property (or control) as a method parameter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

There is method

```
public double getTextWidth(string candidate, TextBox control)
{ 
    ......
}
```

there is TextBox

```
<TextBox Text="test" x:Name="searchBox">
  <TextBox.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyTest" ObjectType="{x:Type testobj:Service }" MethodName="getTextWidth">
      <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>

         ?????

      </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
   </ObjectDataProvider>
 </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

How to do it right, something like this inside `<ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>`?

```
<system:String>searchBox.text</system:String>
<TextBox>searchBox</TextBox>
```

Comment: What you want from the Control, because we can bind the properties, so that property will have the updated data.

Comment: So, I have a trigger for animation `... To="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyTest}}"...` I need calculate current textbox width

Comment: So the animation is done in ViewModel and you want the control over there ?

Comment: After losing focus, I need to reduce the size of the text box to the size of the text if the text is less than the maximum size of the control. The value to be reached is calculated in the method. Animation parameter "To" is binded with a method that returns the calculated width of the text